# Tensorflow: Trouble re-opening queues after restoring a session

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I have a trained model I'm trying to evaluate on a separate dataset, and I'm having trouble with my input pipeline. After restoring the session, and attempting to load the first batch of validation data, the following error is thrown:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.OutOfRangeError: FIFOQueue '_2_input/batch/fifo_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 1024, current size 0)
```

My code is modelled after the `cifar10_eval.py` example ([see here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/d42facc3cc9611f0c9722c81551a7404a0bd3f6b/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_eval.py)).

```
def read_and_decode(filename_queue):
    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
    _, record = reader.read(filename_queue)

    features = tf.parse_single_example(
        record,
        features={
            'image_raw': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
            'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
    })

    label = tf.cast(features['label'], tf.int32)
    image = tf.decode_raw(features['image_raw'], tf.uint8)

    image.set_shape([21*21*1])
    image = tf.cast(tf.reshape(image, (21, 21, 1)), tf.float32)

    return image, label

def inputs(train, batch_size, num_epochs):
    if train:
        filename = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, TRAIN_FILE)
    else:
        filename = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, TEST_FILE)

    with tf.name_scope('input'):
        filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(
            [filename], num_epochs=num_epochs, shuffle=train)

        example, label = read_and_decode(filename_queue)

        min_after_dequeue = 1000
        capacity = min_after_dequeue + 3 * batch_size

        if train:
            example_batch, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
                [example, label], batch_size=batch_size, capacity=capacity,
                min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue)
        else:
            example_batch, label_batch = tf.train.batch([example, label], batch_size=batch_size,
                    capacity = capacity)

        return example_batch, label_batch

def evaluate_model():
    with tf.Graph().as_default():
        images, labels = inputs(train=False, batch_size=1024,
                num_epochs=NUM_EPOCHS)

        keep_prob = tf.Variable(1.0, name='keep_prob', trainable=False)

        logits = inference(images, keep_prob)
        training_error = batch_training_error(logits, labels)
        summary_op = tf.merge_all_summaries()

        sess = tf.Session()

        log_dir = os.path.join(SUMMARY_DIR, "eval2")
        writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(log_dir, sess.graph)

        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        saver.restore(sess, 'checkpoint/model-1280')

        keep_prob.assign(1.0)

        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)

        #threads = []
        #for qr in tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.QUEUE_RUNNERS):
        #    new_threads = qr.create_threads(sess, coord=coord, daemon=True, start=True)
        #    threads.extend(new_threads)

        try:
            step = 0
            while not coord.should_stop():
                err = sess.run(training_error)
                print("Step %d, batch training error: %.3f" % (step, err))

                if step % 10 == 0:
                    summary = sess.run(summary_op)
                    writer.add_summary(summary, global_step=step)
                    print('Summary written.')

                step += 1
        #except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
        #    print('Done training for %d epochs, %d steps.' % (NUM_EPOCHS, step))
        finally:
            coord.request_stop()

        coord.join(threads)
        sess.close()

evaluate_model()
```

I'm new to Tensorflow and I'm having trouble understanding where I've gone wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just a guess, but I would like the tensorflow gods to follow up, I bet that when you're restoring your model, you are restoring the state of your "input_producer" variables. This gives them the state where they give you an out of range error (because that's where they were when you left off). Try investigating and restricting the variables restored by saver

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
```

with

```
saver = tf.train.Saver( tf.trainable_variables() )
```

That did it for me. I stand by my explanation in the comment. You need to avoid restoring the queue(input_producer) states. I also had to append non-trainables like "global_step" that I wanted to keep track of to that list.